# ImportError: cannot import name 'matplotlib_circuit_drawer'

Tags: programming, qiskit

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.tools.visualization import matplotlib_circuit_drawer as drawer
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit import execute
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
```

This is the code cell that I am trying to implement. The error is in the second line.

```
Error--> ImportError: cannot import name 'matplotlib_circuit_drawer'
```

I'm using Google Colab to execute the code. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qiskit.tools.visualization` has been moved to `qiskit.visualization` and `matplotlib_circuit_drawer` has been removed. Instead of using it, try using `qiskit.visualization.circuit_drawer()` with the appropriate arguments.

So in this case it should be `qiskit.visualization.circuit_drawer(my_circuit, output='mpl', filename='my_circuit.png')`